# SELECTING, INSERTING, DELETING and UPDATING a database from the StreamingAssets in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sqlite

I've watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebPZ4OPWAsQ). I think that this is very useful and will answer my problem in Database issue about SQLite in Unity. But as the video goes on there are the file "youtube.bytes" used by the presentor. Later on he use it like this path = Application.datapath +"/youtube.bytes"; What is this byte file and how can I create one to use in my app. I'm an absolute beginner in android dev't. Help me Sir/ Ma'am.

Answer (score 1):

The `.bytes` extension in Unity is used to store *binary data* such as bytes from an image, compiled script unlike a simple text(.txt) file.

In your case, `.bytes` is added to the database file that is created. The database file created is a binary file. All you need to do is change the extension name of the database file created to `.bytes`.

I can't tell why that tutorial chose to use `.bytes`. The `.db` extension [can](https://bravenewmethod.com/2015/04/11/quickstart-sqlite-unity/) still be read with with the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class. This is up to you to decide.

I also noticed that the tutorial is using `Application.datapath +"/youtube.bytes";`. If you want to be able to modify that fie, you should use `Application.persistentDataPath+"/youtube.bytes"`.

Comment: In the second video tutorial, he used the Application.persistentdatapath +"/youtube.bytes" because he built it in android. Thank you for answering. So I need to change the file extension of the database file? Then, I will just put it on the StreamingAssets and use WWW to access it? Can I ask again? On my Assets folder why is it that Unity creates another database file similar to what on my StreamingAssets? The same file name but no data inside. What is this? Sorry, I'm a beginner in Unity. Hope you'll understand :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry. I do not use SQLite. My question is only answering your question "what is .byte and how to create it". Like I said, you create it by renaming the extension of the db file in your scene to .bytes. You may need to go to the folder to do that instead of through Unity Editor.

Comment: If you think that your question is answered, you can go ahead to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer so that the post will be marked as closed.